# How do I install Havit WF30 wireless adapter on Ubuntu on a laptop without a CD drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, wireless-adapter

I put the "installation CD" containing the relevant drivers in another laptop and copied the contents onto flash drive that I inserted in my laptop that is running Ubuntu. I extracted all the files, and there are 20 or so executable ones, including install.sh and install-sh. When I run either of them in Terminal, it asks me where I want to install and the default is /root/ralink. It then asks me the web UI port number, and the default is 8080. When I click ok, the terminal gives me this:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
rm: cannot remove '/root/ralink': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
cp: failed to access '/root/ralink/': Permission denied
cp: failed to access '/root/ralink/': Permission denied
cp: failed to access '/root/ralink/': Permission denied
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 68: cd: /root/ralink/: Permission denied
tar (child): WebUI.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 69: cd: /root/ralink/: Permission denied
tar (child): RT2870.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 70: cd: /root/ralink/: Permission denied
tar (child): WPA_Supplicant.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mv: cannot stat '/root/ralink/RT2870/RT2870STA.dat': Permission denied
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 75: cd: /root/ralink/WebUI/nvram: Permission denied
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 75: ./make_config_file: No such file or directory
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 78: cd: /root/ralink/RT2870: Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ra0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
rmmod: ERROR: Module rt2870sta is not currently loaded
insmod: ERROR: could not load module os/linux/rt2870sta.ko: No such file or directory
ra0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 90: cd: /root/ralink/WebUI/: Permission denied
mv: failed to access '/root/ralink/etc/boa/': Permission denied
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 93: cd: /root/ralink/WPA_Supplicant/: Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'defconfig': No such file or directory
```

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
    cp: failed to access '/root/ralink/etc/boa/': Permission denied
    mv: failed to access '/root/ralink/etc/boa/': Permission denied
    boa: no process found
    /home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 98: cd: /root/ralink/WebUI/boa/src: Permission denied
    make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
    /home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 98: ./boa: No such file or directory
    /home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: line 102: cd: /root/ralink: Permission denied
    You can execute /root/ralink/run.sh to start Browser next time.

In addition to that, Firefox opens the page http://127.0.0.1:8080/Sta/index.html and it says "Unable to connect".

EDIT:
I tried running it with sudo and it gives me this:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
cp: cannot stat 'WebUI.tgz': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'RT2870.tgz': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'WPA_Supplicant.tgz': No such file or directory
tar (child): WebUI.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar (child): RT2870.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar (child): WPA_Supplicant.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mv: cannot stat '/root/ralink/RT2870/RT2870STA.dat': No such file or directory
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 75: cd: can't cd to /root/ralink/WebUI/nvram
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 75: /home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: ./make_config_file: not found
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 78: cd: can't cd to /root/ralink/RT2870
make:**  No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
make:  **No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 81: [: 10: unexpected operator
ra0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
rmmod: ERROR: Module rt2870sta is not currently loaded
insmod: ERROR: could not load module os/linux/rt2870sta.ko: No such file or directory
ra0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 90: cd: can't cd to /root/ralink/WebUI/
mv: cannot stat 'boa.conf': No such file or directory
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 93: cd: can't cd to /root/ralink/WPA_Supplicant/
cp: cannot stat 'defconfig': No such file or directory
make:**  No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: cannot stat 'wpa_supplicant': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'wpa_cli': No such file or directory
boa: no process found
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 98: cd: can't cd to /root/ralink/WebUI/boa/src
make:  **No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: 98: /home/matija/Desktop/install.sh: ./boa: not found
You can execute /root/ralink/run.sh to start Browser next time.

Comment: This seems to be a permission problem. Did you try running it with sudo?

Comment: Yes, just now. I edited the error message into the post.